# Azure logic apps Parse Json throws an error

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, connector

***Background***

I have a custom connector which returns a JSON response .I am trying to parse the response to JSON since i want to use the response later in other flows. So that I am using Parse JSON Action from Data operations connector. Following  is the JSON response and the JSON  schema i provided to Parse JSON.

**Response**

```
[
   [
      {
         "key":"Customer_Key",
         "value":{
            "id":"abfa48ad-392d-e511-80d3-005056b34214",
            "name":"90033"
         }
      },
      {
         "key":"Status",
         "value":"Done"
      }
   ]
]
```

**Schema**

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "key": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "key",
                "value"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
  {
            "message": "Invalid type. Expected Object but got String.",
            "lineNumber": 0,
            "linePosition": 0,
            "path": "[0][2].value",
            "value": "90033",
            "schemaId": "#/items/items/properties/value",
            "errorType": "type",
            "childErrors": []
        },
```

Any one knows what is the issue on this ?How we can I convert  above  json response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `Use sample payload to generate schema` couldn't generate right schema.
So you could go to this **[liquid studio site](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter)** and paste the JSON payload then click the **Generate Schema** button, then you will get the Json Schema.

[image]

And I test the Schema, it worked perfectly.
[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions,please let me know.

Comment: @Thanks make .+1 for referring the Liquid Studio site . It works as expected. The logic apps inbuilt  schema generator doesn't work as expected but the Lquid Studio side does the work for me .

Comment: By the way does this site generate the schema for the Json which has multiple types? Some thing similar mentioned here https://cswr.github.io/JsonSchema/spec/multiple_types/

Comment: @Thabo, I test a simple array data [ "foo", 1, "bar", "1", 2 ], and it worked , but the schema only work for this data,because the schema is not generated with "anyOf" method. So you could ask a new question to get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Schema looks incorrect. try with the below schema:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "id",
                "name"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "key",
            "value"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "key",
            "value"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate . This also work fine. However i have marked George's answer as accepted answer since it contains the reference for generating  schema which is useful for people who experience similar issues. Thanks again .